# Why do these tests fail for this custom Flask session interface?

Tags: python, session, flask, customization

I am writing a hybrid single page web/PhoneGap application in Flask. Since cookies in a PhoneGap application are basically unavailable, I have implemented a custom [session interface](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#session-interface) that completely avoids cookies. It stores session data in the application database and passes the session ID explicitly in the HTTP request and response bodies.

I have created a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/jgonggrijp/session-testcase) with a reduced testcase. It's still a sizeable project in its own right, but the Readme should help you to quickly find your way. The repo includes seven tests that all succeed when using Flask's default cookie-based session interface and all fail with my custom session interface. The main problem appears to be that data are sometimes not retained on the session object, but this is mysterious because the session object inherits from Python's builtin `dict`, which shouldn't spontaneously forget data. In addition, the session interface is straightforward and doesn't seem to make any obvious mistakes compared to [Flask's example Redis session snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/75/).

To make matters more frustrating, the custom session interface seems to work correctly in the actual application. Only the unit tests are failing. However, for this reason it is unsafe to assume that the session interface works correctly in all circumstances.

Help will be much appreciated.

**Edit:** Gist is not accepting the reduced testcase because it includes directories. I am now moving it to a full-blown GitHub repository. I'll update this post again when done.

**New edit:** moved the reduced testcase to a proper GitHub repo. The Readme still mentions "this Gist", sorry.

Comment: A brief skim through your tests suggests that you are not including `t` in your posts, but your main application is.  Not 100% sure as there is a lot to look through.

Comment: @SeanVieira that skim was probably a bit too brief. :-) Sometimes the test posts do indeed not include the `t` field, but then the objective is to confirm that it produces a 40x error. When using Flask's default session implementation, all tests pass.

Comment: I was looking at [this test](https://github.com/jgonggrijp/session-testcase/blob/7b3922427662894378cc6e735da58d3b1838ddd5/reduced_testcase/tests/test_admin.py#L21-L26) which looks like it is expecting a successful response.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, right, sorry for the confusion. That might actually be the problem in that particular test (it's an admin view, which works a bit differently from the other views)! However, in the other six failing tests something else is going on.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could reduce the project to a single snippet :-) anyway, which data is _not_ retained in the `Session` object? I am wondering if this could be _because_ you inherited from `dict`. Some issue with `__setitem__` or `__setattr__`. Do you know how Flask interacts with your `Session` object exactly?

Comment: This testcase is already a significant reduction from the actual project. Please see the unittest output and use your debugging skills for the specifics on what data are not retained. Please see the [Flask SessionInterface documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#session-interface) (and the source code) for details on how Flask interacts with my session implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problems *mostly* come down to providing the session token in your test requests. If you don't provide the token the session is blank.

I assume your actual application is correctly sending the session token and thus appears to work.

It doesn't take much to fix up the test cases to pass correctly.

### Every request attempts to load a session based on a post param

In your session implementation:

```
def open_session(self, app, request):
    s = Session()
    if 't' in request.form:
        ....

    return s
```

This means that every request that is not `POST` (or `PUT`) and doesn't have `t` sent will
have a blank session.

Whereas a cookies based implementation will always have the session token available
and will be able to load previous requests' sessions.

Here is one of your sample tests:

```
def test_authorize_captcha_expired(self):
    with self.client as c:
        with c.session_transaction() as s:
            s['captcha-answer'] = u'one two three'.split()
            s['captcha-expires'] = datetime.today() - timedelta(minutes=1)
        self.assertEqual(c.post('/test', data={
            'ca': 'one two three',
        }).status_code, 400)
```

You have not supplied a `t` value for the post to `/test`. Thus it gets a blank
session which does not have a `captcha-expires` key and a `KeyError` is raised.

### Your session requires a 'token' key for it to be saved

In your session implementation:

```
def save_session(self, app, session, response):
    if session.modified and 'token' in session:
        ...
        # save session to database
        ...
```

Thus when you have:

```
with c.session_transaction() as s:
    s['captcha-answer'] = u'one two three'.split()
    s['captcha-expires'] = datetime.today() - timedelta(minutes=1)
```

No session actually gets written to the database. For any subsequent request to
use. Note that it really **does** need to be written to the database since `open_session` will attempt to load something from the database on every request.

To fix the most of those cases you need to supply a 'token' when creating the session and a 't' with that token for any requests that use it.

Thus the sample test I used above would end up like:

```
def test_authorize_captcha_expired(self):
    with self.client as c:
        token = generate_key(SystemRandom())
        with c.session_transaction() as s:
            s['token'] = token
            s['captcha-answer'] = u'one two three'.split()
            s['captcha-expires'] = datetime.today() - timedelta(minutes=1)
        self.assertEqual(c.post('/test', data={
            'ca': 'one two three',
            't': token
        }).status_code, 400)
```

### You change the token when you respond with json

...but you are not using the new token when you make a subsequent request

```
def test_reply_to_reflection_passthrough(self):
    with self.client as c:
        token = 'abcdef'

        ...

        response2 = c.post('/reflection/1/reply', data={
            'p': 'test4',
            'r': 'testmessage',
            't': token,
        }, ...
```

By here, the post to `/reflection/1/reply` has generated a new
token and saved it, thus the critical key `last-reply` is not in the
session identified by `abcdef`. If this were a cookies based session then `last-reply` would be available to the next request.

So to fix this test... use the new token

```
def test_reply_to_reflection_passthrough(self):
    with self.client as c:

        ...

        response2 = c.post('/reflection/1/reply', data={

        ...

        token = session['token']
        with c.session_transaction(method="POST", data={'t':token}) as s:
            s['token'] = token
            s['last-request'] = datetime.now() - timedelta(milliseconds=1001)

        response3 = c.post('/reflection/1/reply', data={

        ...
```

### A redirect will lose the session token

In the test `test_bump`:

```
def test_bump(self):
    response = self.client.post(
        '/admin/tip/action/',
        data = {'action': 'Bump', 'rowid': '1',},
        follow_redirects=True )
    self.assertIn(' tips have been bumped.', response.data)
```

The post to `/admin/tip/action` returns a redirect.

Here you are checking for the presence of a flash message. And flash messages
get stored in the session.

With a cookie based session the session id is sent again with the subsequent redirected request.

Since your session id is specified as a post value it does not get sent again, the session and the flash messages are lost.

The way to fix this is not to follow redirects but to check the session for data set by flasks flash method.

```
def test_bump(self):
    with self.client as c:
        token = generate_key(SystemRandom())
        with c.session_transaction() as s:
            s['token'] = token
        c.post('/admin/tip/action/',
               data={'action': 'Bump', 'rowid': '1', 't': token})

        with c.session_transaction(method="POST", data={'t': token}) as s:
            self.assertIn(' tips have been bumped.', s['_flashes'][0][1])
```

#### And thats all

I have sent a pull request with the changes as I have described above, you will find that the tests now pass for both the default flask session and your session implementation.